# General solution to first-order ODE in 3D

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Has the ODE
$$
\boldsymbol{y}' = \boldsymbol{\mathsf{M}}\cdot\boldsymbol{y}
$$
(with $\boldsymbol{y}\in R^3$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{M}}$ a constant real-valued 3x3 matrix) a closed solution? If so what is it?

I know the answer for the cases that $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{M}}$ is symmetric or anti-symmetric. But what if $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{M}}=\boldsymbol{\mathsf{S}}+\boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}$ with 
$\boldsymbol{\mathsf{S}}^t=\boldsymbol{\mathsf{S}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}^t=-\boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}$?

Comment: The answer is given as $$y(t) = y(0)e^{Mt}$$ 
where $e^{Mt}$ represents the [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)

Comment: thanks. So I learned about the matrix exponential. Great! (I would accept this comment morphed into an answer ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment: the answer is given as 
$$
y(t) = y(0)e^{Mt}
$$
where $e^{Mt}$ represents the [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), defined by
$$
e^{Mt} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}M^kt^k
$$
where $M^0 := I$.  An equally valid definition is that $e^{Mt}$ is the unique matrix function satisfying
$$
\frac{d}{dt} e^{Mt} = M e^{Mt} = e^{Mt} M\\
e^{M\cdot 0} = e^{0} = I
$$